# Observable.fromPromise does not exist ONLY when building on CircleCI

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, observable, circleci

Can anybody please help me figuring this out. The code fragment below runs in a NodeJS Typescript environment en this works fine on multiple machines across multiple platforms but fails to build on CircleCI with the following:

error TS2339: Property 'fromPromise' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/frompromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

return Observable.fromPromise(col.insertOne(document))
```

What is different in the CircleCI environment that causes this and what would be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it must not be my day. The problem was the capital 'P' in the import statement.

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
```

This is no problem on platforms with a case insensitive filesystem so I didn't notice it on Mac OS/X and also not on Windows. but CircleCI uses Linux.

Answer (score 2):

With RxJS 5.5+, the `Observable` prototype does not include any static methods. For this reason, you will need to take one of two approaches to include the `fromPromise` (and other) static methods.

> RxJS v5.5.2 is the default dependency version for Angular 5.

---

**Approach 1 (preferred option)**

To use the `fromPromise` method, independently import it from `rxjs/observable`.

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
let observable = fromPromise(promise);
```

This approach is beneficial for reducing the bundle size, as it will import only what you need by patching the `Observable` prototype.

---

**Approach 2 (unoptimized approach)**

To use the static `Observable.fromPromise` as you previously have, you will need to import Observable from `rxjs/Rx`.

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

This method will import the entire core set of functionality, resulting in a larger bundle size.

Comment: Thx for the heads-up!